# Deploying portlet needs restarting tomcat server in liferay

Tags: liferay

I have a portlet that has some libraries that I put them in lib->ext folder. Every time I want to do some changes in code and deploy it to server, portal server show classnotfound exception and I can't run my portlet until I restart server.
classnotfound every time is different.
For portlets that don't have any libs in lib->ext folder, I don't have such problem.
I run Liferay 6.2.5 .

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Classes in tomcat's `lib/` or `lib/ext` folder *always* require a restart of Tomcat. I'm assuming that these are updated with deployment as well - it doesn't work this way.

I'm suggesting that you keep these classes in your portlet's `WEB-INF/lib` - at least during development time - and only move them to the global classpath once they're stable.

If you'd update to Liferay 7, you'd be a lot more flexible: When packaged as an OSGi bundle, your components will be truly hot-deployable.

Another option would be to use a tool/JVM that does support the hot replacement of classes - e.g. JRebel (disclaimer: I've not used it myself)

Comment: I don't make changes in libs, I make changes in portlet that uses that libs. libs themselves are be the same. I this also require a restart ?
And thanks for your complete answer.

Comment: In that case: more information needed. Which class is missing? Can you create a minimal project to reproduce? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve also: are you spawning any threads that you might not terminate upon undeploying?

Comment: some general classes like QueryUtil class. I will test minimal project but I don't have any threads.

Comment: Compile your portlet, right click on portlet ->liferay->sdk->compile. after complie lib is replaced by new genrated code.